# insert data into array

Tags: jquery, arrays, asp.net-mvc

I can't insert data into array. I want it as one array. I want to add 12 months in each row. Below is my code:

```
var data = {};
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    data[i] = {
        Name: "Sample",
        Group: "Sample",
        Offering: "India",
        Type: "Employee",
        subject: "Sample",
        sponser: true
    };

    for (j = 1; j <= 12; j++) {
        var val = "m" + j;
        data.val = j + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: data.val = j + 1; need to be data[i].val = j + 1;

Comment: @AmrElgarhy that alone will not work, because `val` is a string and so actually you try to set the property `val` instead of `m1`, `m2`, ...

Comment: @eisbehr what shall i do

Comment: Take a look at my answer. I've posted everything very detailed there, with a porking example too. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your `array` is an `object`! If you want it to be an `array`, you need to change `var data = {};` to `var data = [];`. But it will work the same way, so it makes no difference here.
2. You didn't declared the variable `j` in your second `for` loop. You need to add `var` in front of it, like you did in your first loop.
3. You need to specify the current `index` of your `object / array` you want to set the months to. So write `data[i]` instead of `data` in your second `for` loop.
4. As you want to use the value of `val` as `key` in your `object / array`, you need to put bracers `[]` around it. Otherwise you will only set the property `val` of the object.
5. Your months goes from `1` to `12`. You will only need to set `j` instead of `j + 1`, because you otherwise write the months from `2` to `13`.

```js
var data = {};                       // this is an object
                                     // if it should be an array write 'var data = [];'

for( var i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
    data[i] = {
        Name     : "Sample",
        Group    : "Sample",
        Offering : "India",
        Type     : "Employee",
        subject  : "Sample",
        sponser  : true
    };

    for( var j = 1; j <= 12; j++ ) { // added 'var' before 'j'
        var val = "m" + j;
        data[i][val] = j;            // added '[i]' after 'data'
                                     // changed '.val' to '[val]'
                                     // removed '+ 1' after 'j'
    }
}

console.log(data);
```